# CGRect cropped image shows wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

When I try to crop the bottom of an image the result is zoomed in from the top left. Without the crop the image shows just fine. I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here with the crop function. Why this doesn't return the complete image with the crop? See code and results below:

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImageFromScreenShot
{
    // Prepare view for screen capture

    // Screen Capture

    CGRect fullScreenRect = self.view.bounds;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullScreenRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:fullScreenRect afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Crop Image

    CGFloat cropDistance = 20.0;

    CGSize imageSize = screenShotImage.size;

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectInset(imageRect, 0.0, cropDistance);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenShotImage CGImage], cropRect);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    // Restore view after screen capture


    return croppedImage;
}
```

Crop is going good but the image is zoomed in and smaller:

[image]

Without the cropping the size is just fine from code below:

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImageFromScreenShot
{
    // Prepare view for screen capture

    // Screen Capture

    CGRect fullScreenRect = self.view.bounds;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullScreenRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:fullScreenRect afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return screenShotImage;
}
```

Returns to original image as it also should do with the cropped function:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectInset(imageRect, 0.0, cropDistance);
```

Into:

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width, imageSize.height - cropDistance);
```

You just want to define the specific rect you want as the subset of the image, so if you want to crop the bottom, then you just subtract from the height.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a scaled image on a retina display, but using screen coordinates for the final image size(non-retina). So this gets you the top left corner, minus the frame you removed with the inset frame. Multiply imageSize.width and imageSize.height by [UIScreen mainScreen].scale, and you'll probably get what you were after originally.

```
CGSize imageSize = screenShotImage.size;
imageSize.width *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
imageSize.height *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

In order to only remove the bottom of the image, try this instead of the CGRectInset:

```
CGRect cropRect = imageRect;
cropRect.size.height -= cropDistance;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, where do I have to put this in the code? Do you have a example? Thanks!

Comment: It works, thanks! Only problem now is that it also cropped the top. Is there a way that it only cropped the bottom?

Comment: Maybe CGRectInset isn't what you were after then - that will shrink every side by the inset amount. If you just want to remove the bottom, subtract the amount from the height.